# How many hosts can Ansible control and how it operates in segmented networks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm using the free version of Ansible at the moment. What is the maximum hosts a single Ansible controller can manage?

Also, in a segmented network like the example below, I wasn't too sure but I assume that I need a controller for each network segment. Is this correct?:

1. Segment A = 10.150.10.x
2. Segment B = 10.151.15.x
3. Segment C = 10.25.10.x

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/OilDwJiAAgU [edit] the question with your experience and put some numbers for others. It's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You should move it to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your ansible control server settings(cpu cores, and memory)
if your ansible control server can ssh connect to segment A, B, C, then one control server is enough. if not, you need three control server

Comment: Ah I thought so. Do you have a doc I can reference for the sys reqs? As for the network segment in a windows example, would SSH apply? I seen that as long as there's a WinRM listener, PS 3.0 and  at least .NET 4.0. I also can't seem to find port requirements. Do you happen to know it?